# Why nginx redirects after form submit?

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite, phpmyadmin

I have conf:

```
    location ~ ^/secret(.+) {
            rewrite ^/secret(.+)$ /phpmyadmin$1;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
            root /usr/share/;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;

            auth_basic "Auth";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pass/.pma;

            location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    root /usr/share/;
                    include sites-available/common/php;
            }
            internal;
    }
```

After submit login form of phpmyadmin i've been redirected to `mysite.com/phpmyadmin/index.php?token=...` instead of `mysite.com/secret/index.php?token...`. Why does it behave this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others, who will have the same problem.

1. Check [PMA config](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#basic-settings) for `PmaAbsoluteUri`. By default it equals to `''`. If you have the default value - don't change it.
2. Feel difference between `alias` and `rewrite`. I changed my conf from rewrite to alias and now it works fine.